# What day will (it) be tomorrow?

Tags: word-order

I was told that this is correct:

**What day will it be tomorrow?**

Do you consider this wrong

**"What day will be tomorrow?"**

If it's wrong without "it", why do we not need "it" here?

**What man will come tomorrow?**

Answer (score 1):

What day will it be tomorrow?

When "be" is a linking verb(copula), it needs a subject and a complement

It will be fine tomorrow. Will it be fine tomorrow?
What day it will be tomorrow. What day will it be tomorrow?

What man will come tomorrow?

"come" is intransitive, so you don't need "it"(A man comes here; not a man comes it here)

Comment: "When "be" is a linking verb(copula), it needs a subject and a complement" OK. But why is it not needed here? "What day is today?"

Comment: "today" is both "adverb" and "noun", today is a noun in "What day is today?" and is being used as a subject. See: What is your favorite food? 'What' is an interrogative pronoun and 'your favorite food' is a noun. In questons, verb comes first.

Comment: I still don't understand your point. Day is a noun in both "What day will it be tomorrow?" "What day is today?" But IT is left out in the second. I still don't understand why.

Comment: 'Today is what day.' is a declarative sentence, that is, it's not an interrogative sentence. As you see, 'Today' is a subject in this case. And if we make this sentence a question form(an interrogative sentence), 'is' should come first (subject-verb inversion) — Is today what day?  However, the 'what' which includes also 'day' must come to the head of an interrogative sentence to make it a question form sentence: What day is today? If you add 'it' in this sentence — "What day is it today?"— , today acts like an adverb and the 'it' acts like a 'formal subject'; ex) It's cold.

Comment: What day is today? and What day is it today? are both correct. But why is it that "What day will be tomorrow?" is wrong?

Comment: 'What day will be' lacks subject of 'it'. That is, 'It' is missing. It will be what day.=What day will it be?  We need 'it'.

Comment: How come "What day is today?" is not missing it?

Comment: Because 'today' is a subject, it doesn't matter if you include it or not. If you include 'it', then subejct becomes 'it' and today becomes adverb.

Comment: So, why can't "tomorrow" be a subject then? 1) What day is today? - Today is Monday. 2) What day will be tomorrow? - Tomorrow will be Monday.

Comment: Tomorrow can be a subject.

Comment: I know. So why do we need IT in here "What day will IT be tomorrow?"

Comment: It's because the 'it' has many usages like  'a formal subject' to express weather, time, distance or whatever.

Comment: But you deflect the point to another thing. It's useless.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I mean.